# How to access json inputs

Tags: json, yii

I am working in yii framework.I am having json input as-

```
$json='{"userId":1,"questionPaperId":1;"optionId":2}';
```

So whilw creating functions in yii,i am decoding it and accessing these inputs as-

```
$obj=CJSON::decode($json);
$option=$obj->optionId;
$userId=$obj->userId;
$paperId=$obj->questionPaperId;
```

But its giving error as "Trying to get property of non-object ". So how to access this in yii?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You json string is syntax wrong.

```
$json='{"userId":1,"questionPaperId":1;"optionId":2}'; // note the ; in it
```

should be

```
$json='{"userId":1,"questionPaperId":1,"optionId":2}';
```

Comment: Ya sir i removed that semicolon but still it is giving error as "Trying to get property of non-object".

Answer (score 0):

As CJSON::encode give you a json formatted string from an array, CJSON::decode return an array not an object.

So access it like that: $option=$obj["optionId"];